# sed - how to replace meta character

Tags: sed, metacharacters

In the following example I am looking to include the `*` metacharacter in the string replacement. If I understand correctly, I should be able to escape the character using `\` but after doing that this is the result I am seeing:

```
❯ echo 'foo(*)' | sed s/foo\(\*/bar/g
bar*)
```

I was expecting to see the following:

```
❯ echo 'foo(*)' | sed s/foo\(\*/bar/g
bar)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your sed command:

```
echo 'foo(*)' | sed 's/foo(\*/bar/g'
bar)
```

Comment: ...and not quote `(`, unless you use `-E`/`-r`.